# How many types of accounts are available in quorum

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

In Ethereum two types of accounts are there.EOA and contract account.Does quorum run in samy way that means it is similar like ethereum.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Ethereum, Quorum also only has two types of accounts. Basically it's a geth fork with the following enhancements:

> Privacy - Quorum supports private transactions and private contracts
>   through public/private state separation and utilising Constellation, a
>   peer-to-peer encrypted message exchange for directed transfer of
>   private data to network participants
>
> Alternative Consensus Mechanisms
>   - with no need for POW/POS in a permissioned network, Quorum instead offers multiple consensus mechanisms that are more appropriate for
>   consortium chains
>
> Peer Permissioning - node/peer permissioning using
>   smart contracts, ensuring only known parties can join the network
>
> Higher Performance - Quorum offers significantly higher performance
>   than public geth

They have a very good documentation in their github project.

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum